# How to Print SOAP Message Request Body generated using GSOAP when calling service

Tags: c, web-services, gsoap

I have a java Service and i am calling it from my C program . I generated stubs using GSOAP and when i call the service i get the error message as :

```
Error -21 in function "SOAPDataAdapter::getFieldValueFromXSDElement (XSD -> Dataset conversion)": Feature "12xsd__anyType" is not supported
N5vasco20InvalidDataExceptionE: Error -17 in function "SOAPDataAdapter::getVASCOAttributeFromGSOAP (Attempting to insert WSDL attribute 'User ID' (attribute ID 0) as a dataset value)": The supplied data contains invalid characters
```

My question is how can i print the Soap Message object that is going through GSOAP call . I want to compare it with my SOAPUI request which is working fine.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to view the SOAP message using WIreShark